# git log -- <file_name> works correct on terminal, but doing g.log(file_name) in git python shows error

Tags: python, git, gitpython

For SOME files, it happens that in Git Python the g.log() instruction gives error, but for the same file if I do [$git log -- ] on terminal, that works correct. 
The following command on terminal works very well:

```
$git log -- org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/CompilationUnitVisitor.java
```

Here is my python code:

```
import git
from git import *
import sys
repo = Repo ("/home/directory/git/eclipse.jdt.core")
assert repo.bare == False
g=repo.git
loginfo = g.log('org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/CompilationUnitVisitor.java')
```

It shows the following error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/cmd.py", line 227, in 
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/cmd.py", line 456, in _call_process
    return self.execute(call, **_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/GitPython-0.3.2.RC1-py2.7.egg/git/cmd.py", line 377, in execute
    raise GitCommandError(command, status, stderr_value)
git.exc.GitCommandError: 'git log org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/CompilationUnitVisitor.java' returned exit status 128: fatal: ambiguous argument 'org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/CompilationUnitVisitor.java': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git  [...] -- [...]'

Can someone please suggest how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--` gets lost in the `g.log(...)` call. The correct way to do it would be as follows.

```
g.log('--', "org.eclipse.jdt.core/model/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/CompilationUnitVisitor.java")
```